# Problem with bold line in pattern after I export file from Illustrator into Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, patterns, smartobject, import

[image]

I made pattern in illustrator, imported into Photoshop and I get bold line over all edge lines.

How to remove that problem? Don't know what to do.

I turned off AA in general settings and in pattern-->make option change values so I get rid off those bold lines, and look ok. But when I export that pattern in Photoshop that bold lines comes back again. I made another shape and I get the same result.

I noticed that always happens when I create shape with multiple objects.

For example, I created an object from the image with rectangle and ellipse tool, combine and slice them after to get the big object in the middle so I can surround that smaller object and create pattern. *All objects are perfect match but something I do wrong.*

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, Nenad. It's hard to tell, but are the bold lines happening on the edges of your pattern? If the lines were just a tiny bit off from pixel perfect, it could look thicker along the seams where the pattern pieces bump up next to each other. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, pattern edges seams perfect before I go to ''object-->pattern--->make. I take screenshot after I enter there. I dont have right solution for this, Im lack of experience. Today I somehow managed to make similar pattern with multiple object combined together in one shape (one object). Again I get bold lines. I have hard time in photoshop to make that object nearly perfect. I dont know why that happens. 
---------------------
Yes it make sense, I try that but lines show up, or when I export pattern in PS I also see those bold line over all edge

Comment: Somewhere in the beggining is that problem but I dont see

Comment: Problem was a stroke in the pattern. I made same pattern without stroke and it looks perfect, but when I add stroke pattern have bold lines over all edges.
Does somebody know how to add stroke that patterns looks perfect?

Comment: My guess is there's an issue with rasterizing the artwork because it falls between two pixels instead of exactly on one. It's difficult to determine what's going on here without having the source files, though.

Comment: 1) Are you using decimals on your stroke thickness? Maybe try using only full numbers or .5 decimals.  2) Maybe try using the "expand" function on your strokes before doing the pattern. This way it's one less conversion the software has to deal with.  3) Try doing this at bigger size; you can resize smaller after. It does happen on small or thin lines that some pixels get added or removed since there's no "half pixels"; the software has to either add one or remove one. 4) Since you seem to want to rasterize anyway, why not just rasterize that pattern in Illustrator, then export.

Comment: Maybe the repeat of the pattern create a ticker line? (double line)